# ¿Cómo hacer una multiconsulta MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un problema con el código, no hace la inserción de registros.

Código PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["place_order"]))  {
    require 'php/lib-generadorID.php';
    $idCarrito = generarIDCARRITO();
    $idSesion  = generarIDSESSION();

    $sqlCart = "INSERT INTO carrito(idCarrito, idCliente, idSesion, fechaHora, aux)
        VALUES('$idCarrito', '$idCliente', '$idSesion', now(), '1')";

    $order_details = "";
    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)  {
        $order_details .= "INSERT INTO contenido_carrito(idCarrito, idCliente, idSesion, idArticulo,
            codigoArticulo, codigoAlterno, costo, unidades, subTotal, fechaDeRegistro, aux)
            VALUES('$idCarrito', '$idCliente', '$idSesion', '".$values["product_id"]."', '".$values["product_codArticulo"]."',
            '".$values["product_codAlterno"]."', '".$values["product_price"]."', '".$values["product_quantity"]."',
            '".$values["product_subTotal"]."', now(), '1'); ";
    }
    if(mysqli_multi_query($ConexionBD, $order_details))  {
        unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);  
        echo '<script>alert("You have successfully place an order...Thank you")</script>';  
        echo '<script>window.location.href="venta_refacciones.php"</script>';  
    }  
}
?>
```

Revisé la conexión y está bien, revisé la tabla y no se inserta ningún registro.

Comment: ¿No funcionan ninguno de los dos INSERT o funciona uno sí y el otro no? Creo que debería constar en la pregunta. Luego, ¿has impreso la(s) variable(s) `$sqlCart` y `$order_details` para verificar que se está(n) construyendo bien? Yo usaría consultas preparadas para ese procedimiento para dar más seguridad y eficacia al código.

Comment: el primer INSERT si funciona, el problema llega cuando entra en  foreach y no hace INSERT INTO contenido_carrito, aquí es donde no funciona

Comment: Y si haces `echo $order_details;` antes de hacer el multi query, **¿se imprime una consulta sintácticamente correcta?**. Sería importante que verifiques eso, puede haber errores en alguna parte de la consulta. Por otra parte tu código es deficiente, el if que tienes sólo funciona para la 1ª consulta, si otra falla, no lo sabrás, debes hacerlo dentro de un `while` en el cual llames a `mysqli_more_result`, **[ver ejemplo del Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php)**

Comment: Si tienez razón, ya hice el echo $order_details y me imprime la consulta correctamente, ya vi mi error

Comment: pero aún no funciona la sentencia INSERT

Comment: ¿Podrías probar mi respuesta? Con ella solucionarás problemas de escapado de comillas y, además, te saldrá el mensaje de error en caso de que ese no sea el problema. Prueba y me cuentas qué mensaje te sale y si conseguiste agregar los registros. Por cierto, ¿`$sqlCart` para qué sirve? ¿De dónde obtienes `$idCliente`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin conocer el esquema de la base de datos ni el formulario que envía la información sólo puedo ayudarte a escapar correctamente las cadenas de caracteres que debes incluir en las consultas SQL haciendo uso de [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string) para evitar tanto inyección SQL como que cualquier comilla pueda romper la consulta SQL y provocar errores sintácticos que impidan que se ejecuten los `INSERT`.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['place_order'])) {
    require 'php/lib-generadorID.php';
    $idCarrito = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, generarIDCARRITO());
    $idSesion = mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, generarIDSESSION());

    $sqlCart = "
      INSERT INTO carrito (
        idCarrito,
        idCliente,
        idSesion,
        fechaHora,
      aux) VALUES (
        '$idCarrito',
        '$idCliente',
        '$idSesion',
        NOW(),
        '1'
      )
    ";

    $order_details = "";
    foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values) {
        $order_details .= "
          INSERT INTO contenido_carrito (
            idCarrito,
            idCliente,
            idSesion,
            idArticulo,
            codigoArticulo,
            codigoAlterno,
            costo,
            unidades,
            subTotal,
            fechaDeRegistro,
            aux
          ) VALUES(
            '$idCarrito',
            '$idCliente',
            '$idSesion',
            '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_id"]) . "',
            '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_codArticulo"]) . "',
            '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_codAlterno"]) . "',
            '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_price"]) . "',
            '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_quantity"]) . "',
            '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($ConexionBD, $values["product_subTotal"]) . "',
            NOW(),
           '1'
          );
        ";
    }
    if (mysqli_multi_query($ConexionBD, $order_details) === true) {
        /* Recorremos todos los resultados */
        while (mysqli_more_results($ConexionBD) === true) {
            /* Si hubo un error mostramos el mensaje de error */
            if (mysqli_next_result($ConexionBD) === false) {
                die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($ConexionBD));
            }
        }
        unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
        echo '<script>alert("You have successfully place an order...Thank you")</script>';
        echo '<script>window.location.href="venta_refacciones.php"</script>';
    } else {
        die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($ConexionBD));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: marca este error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp64\www\websites\Monte'Carlo.v-5\check_out_cart.php on line 301         la linea contiene esto: die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($ConexionBD);

Comment: Te falta un paréntesis. ¿Podrías comprobarlo? Debería ser `die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($ConexionBD));`.

Comment: Estoy verificando tu respuesta

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para corregir el error. Gracias.

Comment: Es verdad, con tu respuesta ahora veo mi error, además de que yo apenas estoy comenzando en PHP no sé mucho de seguridad

Comment: Me alegra saber que has encontrado el problema :) los comienzos siempre son duros. Te recomiendo mirar las consultas preparadas, te evitan usar la función de escapado (`mysql_real_scape_string`) y te permiten reutilizar un `INSERT` para insertar múltiples registros en un bucle, sin usar una consulta múltiple con prácticamente el mismo rendimiento.

Comment: el error que tengo: Error SQL: Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'subTotal' at row 1

Comment: Probablemente estás intentando insertar un valor (por ejemplo) `5,25` en vez de `5.25`. Es decir, hay que definir los valores decimales con un punto decimal, no una coma. Con el contenido de la variable `$order_details` podría decirte el motivo exacto.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
$sqlCart =mysqli_query( "INSERT INTO carrito(idCarrito, idCliente, idSesion, fechaHora, aux)
                    VALUES('".$idCarrito."', '".$idCliente."', '".$idSesion."', now(), '1')");
```

Comment: el primer INSERT si funciona, el problema llega cuando entra en  foreach y no hace INSERT INTO contenido_carrito, aquí es donde no funciona